# How to link more than one foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

am working on a banking app, in my Laravel Model, i have a table called transactions.

In that table it has a column called to_id and from_id which is the id of the user that is sending money(from_id) and the id of who is receiving the money(to_id) which is linked to my User table,

here is the CreateTransactionsTable migration code

```
    Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('from_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('from_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->bigInteger('to_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('to_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('Amount');
        $table->enum('TransactionType', ['Credit', 'Debit']);
        $table->enum('Status', ['Completed', 'Incomplete']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

here is the CreateUserTable migration file code

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');            
            $table->string('AccountNumber')->unique();
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
```

Here is the code for the Transactions Model

```
class Transactions extends Model{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Users');
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Users Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'Amount',
    ];

    public function transactions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transactions');
    }
}
```

here's my controller code

```
public function Transactions(){
        $Trans = Transactions::all();
        return view('Admin.TranAdmin')->with(['title'=>'Transaction History ', 'Trans'=>$Trans]);
    }
```

here is my TranAdmin.blade.php code

```
<?php $no = 1; ?>
    @foreach ($Trans as $Tran)  
        <tr>
             <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
             <td>{{ $Tran->to_id }}</td>
             <td>{{ $Tran->from_id->name }}</td>
             <td>{{ $Tran->status }}</td>
             <td>{{ $Tran->created_at->format('F jS, Y')}}</td>
             <td></td>
         </tr>
     @endforeach
```

My problem now is that i cant get the name of the person that sent `$Tran->from_id` and received `$Tran->to_id`  the money

am getting this error

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel Projects\bank\iscbank\resources\views\Admin\TranAdmin.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel Projects\bank\iscbank\resources\views\Admin\TranAdmin.blade.php)

i checked online but i saw was to do `$Tran->User->name`  but since i got two columns that is linked to the users table, how can i do it

Comment: Don't you need to `get()` on the model before being able to use it in a view?

Comment: how, in don't understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you will need to define 2 more relationships on the Transaction model.

like below

as of now, you are trying to access properties of the relation from the attributes from the model (eg : when you do this`$Trans->from_id`, you are simply getting the data, not the relation.) rather you need to access the relation by defining them in the model first and then call the properties on it.

```
class Transactions extends Model{
    public function from(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Users','from_id', 'id');
    }

    public function to(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Users', 'to_id', 'id');
    }

    //maybe you dont need the user relationship at all

}
```

and then in the template, you use it like follows

```
$transaction->to->name;
$transaction->from->name;
```